# RadioButton appearance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, checkbox

I need to change the appearance of a RadioButton for WP7 or at the very least changing the isChecked from a tick to a square. Is there a way to do this or will I have to use something to mimic this?

Answer (score 5):

Use Expression Blend to modify the look of your radiobutton.

A good tutorial to customize your theme: [Creating WP7 Custom Theme - Complex Theme](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-WP7-Custom-Theme---Complex-Theme)

By the middle of the article, he explains how to customize your radiobutton.
Thus, you can customize your radiobutton depending on its state.

Expression Blend is very powerful tool!

Answer (score 0):

Look into modifying the control template.